# How do I turn a select into a delete?

Tags: sql, select, sql-server-2005, sql-delete

In sql server 2005, I have a parent table describing paths, and a child table which contains the coordinates for each point along each path, like this:

## Path

```
int path_id, string path_name
```

## Points

```
int path_id, float x, float y, int n
```

The first point on the path is n=1, and then each new point that is added increments n.

What I need to do is, delete the points returned by this:

```
select [path_id]
from Points
where n=1
```

i.e. the first point in each path, and then also delete all the points where n is the value returned by this:

```
select [path_id], max(n)
from Points
group by [path_id]
```

i.e. the last added point to each path.

For the first part, I can do this:

```
delete from Points
where n=1
```

but how do I do the second part?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
DELETE FROM Points
FROM points
INNER JOIN     
(SELECT point_id, path_id, n
 FROM (SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY path_id ORDER BY n DESC) AS RowNumber, 
              point_id, path_id, n
       FROM points ) t
  WHERE n = 1 or RowNumber = 1 
) t on t.point_id = points.point_id and t.path_id = points.path_id and t.n = points.n
```

Comment: Bassam, I thought I had a unique point_id, but it turns out I don't.  Thanks, though

Comment: @Melanie check it out now.. I changed the join to include path_od and n

Comment: Okay, if I delete everything like t.point_id = points.point_id, then this seems to work.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try this for the second part:

```
DELETE from points where path_id in
(
   Select path_id from (
   select [path_id], max(n)
   from Points
   group by [path_id]
   ) t
)
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think this answer applies to SQL Server, but to show how it can be done with databases that support tuples with the IN operator:

```
DELETE FROM Points
WHERE (path_id, n) IN
    (SELECT path_id, max(n)
     FROM Points
     GROUP BY path_id)
```

Comment: no, it doesn't work, but it does at least make sense to me.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Here's an approach that will work in a pinch:

```
create table dummy as (
  select path_id, max(n)
  from points
  group by path_id
);

delete from points where n in 
  select n from dummy where points.path_id = dummy.path_id
);

drop table dummy;
```